# oracle text definescore with accum and Query rewriting

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

I am using Oracle text to search in a corpus of sentences
I want the scoring to be as counting the discrete occurrences only,

Example : My Query is  `( dog cat table )`
If it found the term " dog " it must count 1 even if the sentence has more than one "dog" term. If it found " dog cat " it must count 2 ... etc

I used this query, but it gives me 51 if it finds the two terms. I need to accumulate the discrete occurrences. So I want to override the behaviour of the scoring algorithm of Oracle Text.

```
   select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(1)*/ sentence_id
           ,score(1) as sc
           , isn 
           ,sentence_length 
   from       plag_docsentences 
   where contains(PROCESSED_TEXT,'DEFINESCORE(dog, DISCRETE*.01)
                                ,DEFINESCORE(cat, DISCRETE*.01)'
                    ,1)>0 
order by score(1) desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I Solved that Issue.

suppose I find 2 terms out of 3, the score will be 67 
which means ( 2/3=67 ) this is the default behavior of oracle text scoring alg.
so I derived an equation to find the number of occurrences (i.e number of terms in query found in the corpus sentence)
as follows:

**x/query_lenght = score/100**

then

**x=query_lenght * score/100**

this will find the number of matching words between the query and the corpus query

I hope this will help reasearchers in IR.

Comment: but still ther a problem , the score never 100%, any Idea?